# Echo mysql Query Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is:
I have a table called Stations, and it has 100 columns.  I want to select all records from Stations and randomly select 1 record and echo the random record.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
<?PHP

$connect = mysql_connect("***", "****", "****") or  die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("***");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stations ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

$Station = $rows['Station1'];///seems it will only show Station1 Column I have Station1 to Station100 was not sure how to add rest of Stations

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Cool, what is your question now? Move on to PDO, **stop using `mysql_*`, it is deprecated and unsafe!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're limiting the result set to only one row, you don't need *that* `while()` loop. Just fetch the row from the result set and use it afterwards, like this:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Now comes to your question,

> ... it will only show Station1 Column I have Station1 to Station100 was not sure how to add rest of Stations

To display all hundred column values, it's better to use a `for` loop like this,

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i){
    // display $rows['Station' . $i] as per your choice. Below is one way.
    echo $rows['Station' . $i] . '<br />';
}
```

**Update:**

From your comment,

> ... I need it to randomly choose 1 value out of all 100 columns and echo that value please

After fetching the row from the result set, use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function to get a random key out of the array, and then use that key to display the column value, like this:

```
$randKey = array_rand($rows);
echo $rows[$randKey];
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions instead. Also read, [why shouldn't I use `mysql_*` functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for everyones help, Rajdeep i have used your code above and it shows all my column data.  what i need it to do is all my columns have 1 row with a name in it.  I need it to randomly choose 1 value out of all 100 columns and echo that value please

Comment: @user3015877 I've updated my answer, please see the **Update** section of my answer.

Comment: Rajdeep, Thanks for the help, that did the trick, appreciate very much.